# Why "docker-compose up" fails for Next.js?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

Following this tutorial how to run Next.js app in production: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNh8iShFXto

But for me `docker-compose up` return an error. Why? What do I miss?

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro vapor-cloud-portal % docker-compose up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Maybe it matters, but using this template for my Next.js app: https://themeforest.net/item/materialize-material-design-admin-template/11446068

Comment: Apparently, you do not have `docker` installed. See [GitHub issue #5120](https://github.com/prisma/prisma1/issues/5120)

Comment: If I simply write `docker` in terminal, it returns, terminal recognise it ..

Comment: ahh, but I was not running Docker on my Mac :( It runs now, and `docker-compose up` works now.

Comment: I just went off of the GItHub issue; feel free to self-answer with more correct details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not running Docker, and seems it is required to run `docker-compose up`.